# Linux commands in Python subprocesses

Tags: python, linux, bash, process

I'm executing a set of commands that first require me to call `bash`. I am trying to automate these commands by writing a Python script to do this. My first command obviously needs to be `bash`, so I run

```
p = subprocess.call(['bash'])
```

and it launches the bash shell no problem.

Where I then have problems is trying to execute the remaining code in the bash environment. I thought perhaps there was a need for process communication (i.e. redirecting stdout as in

```
p0 = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['bash'], stdin=p0.stdout)
p1.communicate()
```

) but the piping doesn't seem to solve my problem.

How can I write this script so that it mimics the following sequential Linux commands?

```
$ bash
$ cmd1
$ cmd2
...
```

I'm working with Ubuntu 14.04 and Python 2.7.6.

Thanks in advance for the guidance!

Comment: Are those commands related at all? Do they need to be run in the same shell session? Do they need to be run under an interactive bash session?

Comment: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2011/04/how-use-bash-shell-python-subprocess-instead-binsh/ may be of some help

Comment: @Busturdust I've actually already gone through that blog--but ah! I missed the executable parameter. That may work!

Comment: @EtanReisner: The commands are all related. In general, what I have to do is open a terminal, execute `bash` and then execute `cmd1`. Then open another terminal, execute `bash` and then execute `cmd2`, and so on. In other words, each command runs a process that must be running in bash when I launch the subsequent process

Comment: So then the answer to my question is "no" and manually running `bash` only matters if your normal shell *isn't* already `bash` I would imagine. In which case you probably just want to `subprocess.call` (or `call_check` or whatever the safer version of that function is) the command `bash -c cmd` (or just `cmd` if the manual `bash` isn't actually necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import subprocess

def bash_command(cmd):
    subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')

bash_command('[your_command]')
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks! From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):  "If shell=True, on Unix the executable argument specifies a replacement shell for the default /bin/sh"

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call run bash separately. You can run something like:

```
p1 = subprocess.call(['cmd1'])
p2 = subprocess.call(['cmd2'])
```

If you must run bash for some reason (the commands contain bash statements, for example), you can run `bash -c "cmd1; cmd2"` from `subprocess.call()`.

Edit: As Busturdust pointed out, you can also try setting `shell=True`, but that uses sh, not bash. But that may be enough for you.

Comment: In fact, I think the key is not the shell parameter, but the executable parameter. From the docs: "On Unix with shell=True, the shell defaults to /bin/sh" so changing the executable parameter changes the shell

Comment: @marcman: I meant the default. Changing the executable does change the shell, but I generally find it more straightforward to specify the shell directly as a part of the command - on the rare occasion I need to change it.

Comment: Gotcha. Is there a particular reason for that, or is it just a personal choice? That is, is that a standard convention?

Comment: More of a personal choice. I (and anyone else reading the code) can see exactly what command is being run without having to look at the documentation for what the executable parameter means. You can choose whatever you feel more comfortable with, of course.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the help!